# change active class of ul list using anchor tag click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add or remove active class for list element by clicking the link inside it.

```
<ul>
   <li id="l1" class=""><a href="javascript:;" class="btn1"> one</a></li>
   <li id="l2" class=""><a href="javascript:;" class="btn2">two</a></li>                                                   
</ul>

 $('.btn1').click(function() {     
    $( "#l1" ).addClass( "active" );   
    $( "#l2" ).removeClass( "active" );        
    window.open ('/one');

});

$('.btn2').click(function() {       
    $( "#l2" ).addClass( "active" );
    $( "#l1" ).removeClass( "active" );     
    window.open ('/two');

});
```

My html and css classes as above. But it doesn't work as expected. So anyone know how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.btn').click(function() {     
    $('.btn').closest('li').removeClass("active")
    $(this).closest('li').addClass("active")  
    console.log($(this).data("url"))
})
```

```css
li.active{color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
   <li id="l1" class=""><a href="javascript:;" class="btn" data-url="/one"> one</a></li>
   <li id="l2" class=""><a href="javascript:;" class="btn" data-url="/two">two</a></li>                                                   
</ul>
```

Comment: this is useful. But instead of printing the url I need to navigate to it. If we do so, then page get refreshed and lost the active class

Answer (score 1):

> My HTML and CSS classes as above

Basically, your code works well. You need to add CSS like `.active{ color:red;}`.

However, listen to the event `click` for each button is not a good thing to do. Imagine you have about 10/100/1000 button then you have to Copy/Pase code like this?

You should keep in mind that: [Don't repeat yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

So as a result, I've refactored code for you like below. Cheers!

```js
$('.btn').click(function() {     
    $('.btn').closest('li').removeClass("active");   
    $(this).closest('li').addClass("active");  
    
    var content = $(this).data('value');
    $("#content").html(content);
});
```

```css
.active{
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
   <li id="l1" class=""><a href="javascript:;" data-value="Content1" class="btn"> one</a></li>
   <li id="l2" class=""><a href="javascript:;" data-value="Content2" class="btn">two</a></li>   
</ul>
<div id="content" style="width:100px; height: 100px">

</div>
```

**Edit**

Basically, you should get content then assign it to `div content` below instead of navigating. If you still want to navigate, you should store your data by using [`localStorage`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp)

Comment: window.open() take different url parameters and once the page get refreshed actives classes will get removed. So how can I prevent that?

Comment: I've just updated my answer. Basically, you should get content then assign it to `div content` below instead of navigating. If you still want to navigate, you should store your data by using [`localStorage `](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(".btn1").click(function(){
$("ul li").removeClass('active'); 
$("#l1").toggleClass('active');
window.open ('/one');
});
```

Note line 2
// will remove class active from all bullets in all list add a #id to the selector to specify a specific list.

Comment: window.open() should take different parameters upon the clicking

Comment: You options are simple here try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-and-not-a-new-window for your window.open (look below main answer for trick to resolve this for you , but not recommended) although you could use Ajax if content is local or cURL if not.

Answer (score 0):

```js
 // One click handler for all buttons/links.
 $('.btn').click(function(event) {
    // Remove class from all buttons.
    $('.btn').parent().removeClass('active');
    // Get the specific button that was clicked.
    var btn = $(this);
    // Add active class to it's parent.
    btn.parent().addClass('active');
    //open from the data-link attribute on the link. 
    // though, window.open will probably be blocked by the browser popup blocker.
    window.open(btn.attr('data-link'));

});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
a.btn {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
   <!-- you could save where to link to in a data attribute, though I am not sure why you wouldn't just have it in href -->
   <li id="l1" class=""><a href="/one" data-link="/one" class="btn btn1"> one</a></li>
   <li id="l2" class=""><a href="/two" data-link="/two" class="btn btn2">two</a></li>                                               
</ul>
```